# Wireless Gyro/Accelerometer Sensors for Raspberry Pi

Tags: wireless, arduino, mpu6050

Is there a way to have a wireless gyro/accelerometer sensor connected to Raspberry Pi?

Have worked with single MPU-6050 in the past. Was wondering if there was a way to have a wireless sensor instead.

I was thinking along this line. If I could have the MPU6050 connected to some bluetooth module both mounted on an arduino I could find out a way to connect the arduino and the pi. Would this work? Any directions would help. Newbie to this domain.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Brutal. Anyway.
Looked at the Arduino wifi shield.
Then I looked at connecting Arduino with a Bluetooth module. Looked for any wireless versions similar to MPU6050, couldn't find any.

Comment: Why was that not in the question?  Why did you reject those solutions?  Why should we waste our time suggesting solutions you have already rejected?

Comment: Ok. Sorry. That is right. One of the things about being new to a field is not knowing what is relevant as well. I thought I had provided the necessary info. I rejected the Arduino Wifi Shield solution because it did not seem efficient, the shield seemed to be priced much higher than the board. Then I imagined bluetooth would be another option and I realized it is a cost effective solution as well. That is why I have that in my original question, as a summary of what I searched for, for the sake of brevity.